# Boost regex: Undefined references when linking

Tags: c++, boost

Until some weeks ago, using the **boost_regex** library I used to compile a C++ file `test.cpp` using the following command.

```
g++-4.9 -Wall -O3 -march=native -flto -DNDEBUG -o test \
 --std=c++14 test.cpp -lboost_regex -pthread
```

The compilation **was working perfectly**. But at some point, I needed to **upgrade my OS** (more precisely, it was Ubuntu 14.04, now it is Ubuntu 16.04).

I kept my local folders with my data, and I also **installed the Boost library again** in the new system, including boost_regex.

The Boost version in the new system is 1.58, unfortunately I cannot know which Boost version I was using before because it is now deleted.

I try to compile again the same file in the new system, with the same command as above, and the linker says it **cannot find two functions** called `maybe_assign` and `construct_init`. If I replace the `-o test` option with just `-c` (i.e. without linking) then the program is compiled without errors.

More precisely, when I try to do linking I get the following errors (they were extremely long, I hade to shorten using `...` dots).

```
In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<...>::match_match()':

undefined reference to `boost::match_results<...>::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<...> const&)'


In function `bool boost::regex_search<...>(...)':

undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<...>::construct_init(...)'


In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<...>::match_prefix()':

undefined reference to `boost::match_results<...>::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<...> const&)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I really don't know how this is possible, the libraries seem perfectly installed, nothing seems missing, and the compilation was working with a previous OS installation (then I guess older libraries).

At these point my only guess could be that Boost authors removed such functions? (maybe they are obsolete?). But I didn't find any trace of this on internet. If this is the case, how can I know the **boost versions** in which such functions are available?

Am I doing any mistake? Do you have any suggestions to investigate about this?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have already checked all the apparently similar questions, but they actually talk about different problems in which just adding the option `-lboost_regex` solves the problem, but I am already using this option.

Comment: "the technical staff in my office had to upgrade my OS" - that's very off-topic. Also, you're programming C++ with Boost, but you're not "technical"? On a hunch, try removing all intermediate build artefacts (ie. force a full rebuild).

Comment: Show your exact command you are using to compile and link your program.

Comment: By the way, since 1.58 is the default for Xenial https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/libboost-dev, likely you had 1.54 before: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/libboost-dev

Comment: @n.m. It's already there

Comment: @sehe oh I see.

Comment: I had to explain why suddenly the same compilation in the same machine stopped working, are you suggesting to write it somehow differently? Maybe without mentioning the technical staff? I can do this...

I am not programming with Boost, I have modified a file which uses Boost to extend its capabilities for my purposes, I really don't know what the existing code (the code not written by me) is doing with the Boost libraries.

Comment: "By the way, since 1.58 is the default [...]"
Many thanks for this hint @sehe , but still I cannot know which version I had before, since I don't know whether it was the latest one (1.54) or some previous non-updated version.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You own your problem. The fact that "someone else" updated the system is irrelevant

Comment: Are you using `gcc` provided by the OS? It looks like Ubuntu 16.04 supplies GCC 5.x. Are you sure you want to use gcc-4.9?

Comment: It's worth a bet. You said "it was Ubuntu 14.04" - so there's that. I agree it's not likely to be of help solving it.

Comment: @n.m. Oooh. A very good point. ISTR that 16.04 _does_ configure GCC 5.x to be ABI compatible. But you know, that might go for standard libraries, not for boost?

Comment: @n.m. and @sehe many thanks for this! Now I am getting different linking errors, then I guess that those linking error are not occurring anymore! The trick, hopefully, seems to be compiling with `g++-5` instead of `g++-4.9` ... I am double checking to make sure and I will keep you updated in at most a couple of hours... many thanks!

Comment: @sehe It pertains to all libraries. To gcc, the old-abi-string and the new-abi-string are simply two different types. Any library that uses std::string is affected..

Comment: @n.m. Like I said, I _thought_ I remember it being configured backwards-compatible but maybe I misremember (it could be the package for gcc-5.x on 14.04 obviously)

Comment: It worked! By using `g++-5` instead of `g++-4.9` now it is compiling with no errors. Many thanks to @n.m. and to @sehe for your very good help.... if one of you could put your suggestions as an official answer I am happy to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR use gcc5.

Ununtu 16.04 comes with gcc5 by default. Every C++ library in it is compiled with that compiler.

Now there was an incompatible C++ ABI change between gcc4 and gcc5. It made binaries built from C++ sources with gcc4 incompatible by default with binaries built with gcc5. This incompatibility often manifests itself as a bunch of undefined symbols that reference `std::string` and/or `std::list`.

The standard library comes built with a dual ABI to support objects built with older compilers. Other libraries like boost, hovever, don't.

Comment: Many thanks @n.m. ! Switching to `g++-5` (instead of `g++-4.9`) solved the problem...